# Why is $\ln(\zeta(s))\sim \ln\big(\frac{1}{s-1}\big) $ as $s\to 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I have shown that $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole at 1. Now,I need to show that $\ln(\zeta(s))\sim \ln\big(\frac{1}{s-1}\big) $ as $s\to 1$.

I know I can write:
$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\psi(s)$ where $\psi(s)$ is holomorphic. But after that I'm stuck.

Any Hints or Suggestions?

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic with a simple pole at $s=1$ means $\zeta(s) = \frac{F(s)}{s-1}$ with $F(s)$ analytic and $F(1)\ne 0$ which means $$\log \zeta(s) = -\log (s-1) +\log F(s)$$ where $\log z$ is analytic around $F(1)$ thus $\log F(s)$ is analytic around $s=1$. Since $F(1)=1$ we have $|\log F(s)|\le C|s-1$ for some $C$.

Comment: But is $log(z_1z_2)=log(z_1)+log(z_2)$. I think it should be $log(z_1z_2)=log(z_1)+log(z_2)+2\pi ik$. In which case we need to calculate the limit of -log(s-1) as s goes to 1

Comment: I.e. $\frac{log(\zeta(s))}{log(\frac{1}{s-1})}=1+\frac{log F(s)}{log(\frac{1}{s-1})}+\frac{2\pi i k}{log(\frac{1}{s-1})}$

Comment: I think $|log(\frac{1}{s-1})|\rightarrow \infty$ as s goes to 1 so the result should follow then right